# Why is installing a system to the top subvolume in btrfs bad?

Tags: linux, system-installation, btrfs

I am trying to install Linux on btrfs. It looks like people are saying that there should be a root btrfs subvolume in which the system should be installed. Right now I have an install working where there is no root subvolume and the system is installed to the top subvolume. So my question is, why is installing a system without a root subvolume bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a separate system volume is 'cleaner' because you can have subvolumes that are not visible on your fs.

E.g. if you have a subvol `/snapshot` it will appear on your fs:

```
$ ls /
bin  boot/  dev/  etc/  ... snapshot/
```

If you have your system in its own volume you can make the subvols on the same level in the hierarchy (they won't show up in `ls /` and need to be mounted separately):

```
os
snapshot
```

You also cannot switch out subvol 5 for another one. If this bothers you, you can make a snapshot of your `/` subvol, change the default subvol to it and then remove the system from subvol 5.